# Programmatically check/uncheck values of a DataPilot row field with the uno library

Tags: java, c#, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, uno

I want to be able to programmatically filter a Calc DataPilot (pivot table) with C# or Java.

At the moment, I am able to do the below:

1. go to the sheet that contains the DataPilot
2. get a reference to the DataPilot
3. Read its rowfields
4. Get a reference to the rowfield of interest

**Pending:**

1. By default, all values under the row field are checked. From that list, I want to be uncheck all of them and keep only specific.

Is this doable programmatically? If yes, what is the missing code to achieve this?

**Current code**

```
XSpreadsheetDocument xSpreadsheetDocument = (XSpreadsheetDocument)document; 
XSpreadsheets xSpreadsheets = xSpreadsheetDocument.getSheets(); 

//mSheetName is the name of the sheet that has the DataPilot I want to filter 
// get reference to the sheet that has my DataPilot 
XSpreadsheet sheet = (XSpreadsheet)xSpreadsheets.getByName(mSheetName).Value; 

//Get a reference to the DataPilot that I want to uncheck/check its row field values 
XDataPilotTablesSupplier xSupplier = (XDataPilotTablesSupplier)sheet; 
XDataPilotTables xSheetPilotTables = xSupplier.getDataPilotTables(); 

//mPivotTableName is the name of the DataPilot 
uno.Any xDPTableObj = xSheetPilotTables.getByName(mPivotTableName); 
XDataPilotTable xPilotTable = (XDataPilotTable)xDPTableObj.Value; 
XDataPilotDescriptor xDPDesc = (XDataPilotDescriptor)xPilotTable; 

// get available row fields
XNameAccess rowFields = (XNameAccess)xDPDesc.getRowFields(); 

//get the row field of interest 
//mFieldName is the name of the row field 
uno.Any xRowItemObj = rowFields.getByName(mFieldName);
```

Example: if we assume the xRowItemObj has 2 checked values (e.g. 1 and 2) how do I keep value 1 checked only?

So far, any research in forums and libreOffice Documentation did not return a result. I am not even sure if it is doable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the list of items from the row field. Here is a Basic example that checks even-numbered boxes.

```vb
oRowItem = oDPTable.getRowFields().getByIndex(0)
oItems = oRowItem.getItems()
For i = 0 To oItems.getCount() - 1
    oItem = oItems.getByIndex(i)
    If (i Mod 2 = 0) Then
        oItem.setPropertyValue("IsHidden", False)
    Else
        oItem.setPropertyValue("IsHidden", True)
    End If
Next
```

If you haven't yet, be sure to use an introspection tool such as [MRI](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/mri-uno-object-inspection-tool).

Comment: Thank you Jim. I was able to proceed due to your answer